# How to enable php_mbstring and php_exif extension on linux shared hosting

Tags: php, linux, apache, exif

I want to enable php_exif and php_mbstring extension on Linux shared hosting.

I downloaded php.ini (not sure whether it is correct or not) by reading [this](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9314/2219/how-to-edit-phpini-on-shared-servers) and [this](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9310/2219/suphp-directive-for-phpini-on-shared-servers) . but I didn't find mbstring and exif extension on my php.ini. I downloaded for PHP 5.4 (my server runs on ot).

Please help me to enable mbstring and exif extension.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you hosting on `namecheap`? If so, according to this - https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9697/0/php-modules-and-extensions-on-shared-hosting-servers both of them should already be enabled.

Comment: No i am not hosting on namecheap.

Comment: Normally you can enable it by compiling php with --enable-exif,
but on a shared hosting you should really consult the docs of your hosting service (instead of the namecheap ones you used)...

Comment: Thank you Yoav. I am not getting any help from my hosting company.

Comment: It's a shame, I expect support to be a part of deal... If you'll give more details, I can try to find something for you.